# Cambiar nombre de excel en javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo una función para descargar una tabla HTML en excel con javascript, pero por defecto el nombre lo coloca descarga.xls, quisiera cambiarle ese nombre alguien podría ayudarme?

Coloco código de ejemplo

```
$("#btnExport").click(function(e) {
        var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
        , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=UTF-8"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
        , base64 = function (s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
        , format = function (s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) { return c[p]; }) }

        var table = 'dvData';
        var name = 'reporte';


        if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
         var ctx = { worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML }
         window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
});
```

Answer (score 0):

En vez de esto:

```
window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
```

Escribe esto:

```
  const a = document.createElement('a');
  a.download = 'nombre_nuevo.xls';
  a.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
  a.click();
```